# Libreoffice shell_exec failed inside PHP Script

Tags: php, shell, docx, libreoffice

I am having an Issue while running libreoffice from shell_exec inside a php script. This script is for converting DOCX to HTML via Libreoffice. The script is working well in terminal but not inside web browser. I have also tried to setup HOME  to /tmp, but not working at all.

```
<?php

$soffice_path = '/usr/sbin/soffice';
$path_with_perm_777 = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/tmp'; 
$docx_file = __DIR__ . '/sample.docx';

echo `which soffice`;
echo `whoami`;
echo shell_exec('echo ${PATH}');

$command = escapeshellcmd('export HOME="/tmp"') . " && " . escapeshellcmd($soffice_path.' --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir '. $path_with_perm_777 .'/converted/ '.$docx_file);          

var_dump( shell_exec($command) );
```

Output in terminal :-

```
/usr/bin/soffice
jack
${PATH}:/usr/bin/custom/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin
string(175) "convert /opt/lampp/htdocs/sample.docx -> /opt/lampp/htdocs/tmp/converted//sample.pdf using filter : writer_pdf_Export Overwriting: /opt/lampp/htdocs/tmp/converted//sample.pdf"
```

Output in web browser :-

```
/usr/sbin/soffice
jack
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/bin
NULL
```

Output of ( `ls -l /opt/lampp/htdocs/` ) :

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 jack jack 4096 Jan 23 13:50 tmp
```

System Info:

> PHP 5.6.39, Manjaro Linux 18.0.2, LibreOffice 6.1.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I fixed it. After Inspecting /opt/lampp/logs/error_log, I got these three lines :-

> /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6:
> version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by
> /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_sal.so.3)
>
> /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6:
> version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by
> /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_sal.so.3)
>
> /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6:
> version 'CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by
> /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libuno_sal.so.3)

LibreOffice could not find required libraries because of missing LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable. After setting up LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LibreOffice successfully converted DOCX Document to PDF File.

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib:/usr/lib32:/usr/local/lib"') . ' && ' . escapeshellcmd('export HOME="/tmp"') . ' && ' . escapeshellcmd($soffice_path.' --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir '. $path_with_perm_777 .'/converted '.$docx_file);
var_dump( shell_exec($command) );
```

Output in Web Browser:-

> string(175) "convert /opt/lampp/htdocs/sample.docx ->
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/tmp/converted/sample.pdf using filter :
> writer_pdf_Export Overwriting:
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/tmp/converted//sample.pdf "